# Remove values from Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I have an ecommerce Angular app in which I have a shared component called `HeaderComponent` and inside that component I have a component called `ShoppingWidgetsComponent`. I called `ShoppingWidgetsComponent` inside of `HeaderComponent` to show number of items in cart on header like this

**header.component.ts**:

```
<div class="main-menu-wrapper-2" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
  <mat-toolbar class="top-navbar top menu">
    <app-shopping-widgets [shoppingCartItems]="shoppingCartItems"></app-shopping-widgets>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**:

```
constructor(private cartService: CartService) {
  this.cartService.getItems().subscribe(shoppingCartItems => this.shoppingCartItems = 
  shoppingCartItems);
}
```

**cart.service.ts**:

```
public cartItems: BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
  const itemsStream = new Observable(observer => {
    observer.next(products);
    observer.complete();
  });
  return <Observable<CartItem[]>>itemsStream;
}
```

**shopping-widgets.component.html**:

```
<button mat-button class="flex-row-button mat-button" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
  <div class="mat-button-wrapper">
    <div class="">
      <mat-icon class="mat-icon-lg mat-icon material-icons">local_grocery_store</mat-icon>
      <span class="cart-count-wrapper">{{ shoppingCartItems.length }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="top-cart">
      <span>{{ getTotal() | async | currency:productService?.currency:'symbol' }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</button>
```

**shopping-widgets.component.ts**:

```
@Input() shoppingCartItems: CartItem[] = [];
```

Now I want to reset the `cartItems` `BehaviourSubject` so that `cartItems` count should display 0 again inside of `shopping.component.html`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you store the state outside of the subject, and control the state management via your service interface - as opposed to exposing the subject itself - then it should be fairly simple

cart.service.ts

```
private cartItems: CartItem[] = [];
private cartItems$: Subject<CartItem[]> = 
  new BehaviorSubject<CartItem[]>(this.cartItems.slice());

getItems(): Observable<CartItem[]> {
  // hide subject implementation from observers
  return this.cartItems$.asObservable();
}

addItem(cartItem: CartItem): void {
  this.cartItems.push(cartItem);
  this.onUpdate();
}

removeItem(cartItem: CartItem): void {
  const index = this.cartItems.indexOf(cartItem);
  if (index === -1) {
    remove;
  }

  this.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
  this.onUpdate();
}

private onUpdate(): void {
  this.cartItems$.next(this.cartItems.slice());
}
```

A copy of the item array is always returned to late subscribers. Items are added and removed via the service interface. Subscribers receive updates when items are added or removed.

I am slicing the array to ensure the service array can not be modified outside the service. This wouldn't protect the cart items themselves from being modified.